# How do I customize Django's Flatpage to display a new field on the change list page of the admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

In my flatpage admin change list page, `mysite.com/admin/flatpages/flatpage/`, I can see the fields:

1. URL
2. Title

Is there a way to also show the field Site?  I associate my flatpages to specific sites. The bad way to do it is by going to the actual Flatpage admin source `django/contrib/flatpages/admin.py` and create a method which will display sites for a Flatpage on the change list page.

I am basically looking for a way to overwrite a django.contrib application on the admin side.

Comment: Alasdair's got a good answer below, but you do know that the default admin for Flatpage does include the site field, it's just in an extra fieldset that's collapsed by default?

Comment: @Carl If I go to an individual flatpage, eg `admin/flatpages/flatpage/1` I can see the sites, but Thierry wanted to add a column listing sites to the flatpage change list view `admin/flatpages/flatpage/`. Unless I'm mistaken, the only columns by default are `title` and `url`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to edit flatpages/admin.py. Instead, create a `CustomFlatPageAdmin` that inherits from the default `FlatPageAdmin`.

You might want to create a `customflatpage` app for the following admin.py file, or perhaps you already have a utilities app that you can add it to.

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.contrib.flatpages.admin import FlatPageAdmin

def get_sites(obj):
    'returns a list of site names for a FlatPage object'
    return ", ".join((site.name for site in obj.sites.all()))
get_sites.short_description = 'Sites'

class CustomFlatPageAdmin(FlatPageAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'url', get_sites)

#unregister the default FlatPage admin and register CustomFlatPageAdmin.
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, CustomFlatPageAdmin)
```